# How to test if the owner of a calendar event declined it?

Tags: google-apps-script

`ev.getMyStatus()` returns `GuestStatus.OWNER`, but that doesn't say if the owner declined the event. Is there a way to test that?

Answer (score 1):

You can not get this from the built-in CalendarApp service, you'll have to use the [Advanced Calendar API service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced). Look at the "attendees" field in the ["events" object](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Scan the result from [event.getGuestList(true)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getGuestList(Boolean)) and look for the owner's email address. Unlike [event.getMyStatus()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getmystatus), the guest status from getting the guest list seems to be correct, even for the event owner.

```
// test if event owner declined
event.getGuestList(true).some(g => 
  g.getEmail() == "put owner's email address here" &&
  g.getGuestStatus() == CalendarApp.GuestStatus.NO)
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer! I needed this a long time ego, but it's nice to know my problem is now solved :)